# PHP : format an html <div> to display it correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

Hello I want to get this but when I store my div in my database and when I try to display it I can't display it correctly can you help me?

Desired outcome:

```
<div data-tpl="header1" data-title="Header 1" class="drop-element"><label>LABEL 111</label></div>
<div data-tpl="header2" data-title="Header 2" class="drop-element"><input class="form-control" value="" id="changeInput" placeholder="INPUT 222"></div>
```

In my database :

```
<div data-tpl=\"header1\" data-title=\"Header 1\" class=\"drop-element\"><label>LABEL 111</label></div>
<div data-tpl=\"header2\" data-title=\"Header 2\" class=\"drop-element\"><input class=\"form-control\" value=\"\" id=\"changeInput\" placeholder=\"INPUT 222\"></div>
```

Display on the web page using this function on my page.php but the display is not correct :

```
preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $formChaine);
```

unwanted result I have on the web page:

```
<div data-tpl="\&quot;header1\&quot;" data-title="\&quot;Header" 1\"="" class="\&quot;drop-element\&quot;"><label>LABEL 111</label></div>
<div data-tpl="\&quot;header2\&quot;" data-title="\&quot;Header" 2\"="" class="\&quot;drop-element\&quot;"><input class="\&quot;form-control\&quot;" value="\&quot;\&quot;" id="\&quot;changeInput\&quot;" placeholder="\&quot;INPUT" 222\"=""></div>
```

Comment: you know you should `serialize` your data before storing it in the database, and `unserialize` it to get best results instead of this 'preg_replace' you are doing.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: @Forbs no, absolutely not. serialize and unserialize have very little business being used in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is being escaped probably as a security measure to protect your database from sequel injection.  You need to unescape it to display it.  You could do it on the php side with stripcslashes when you read it from the database:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php.

Comment: No, something was _not_ done properly here. The escaping is a measure applied to the data while it is _send_ to the database - it does not mean that those escape characters actually _land in_ the database. (Well in this case here apparently they did, but _that_ is the actual issue that should be fixed here.)

Comment: I think you are right.  It was probably escaped when it was sent to server, probably by the server.  A database wouldn't care if a " was in a string, so the \&quot; doesn't make any sense.  The strip slashes function would still work here, but it would be better to get to the root cause of why this was being entity encoded before it was being inserted into the database.

Comment: Here's a good quote:  "The addslashes() is sometimes incorrectly used to try to prevent SQL Injection. Instead, database-specific escaping functions and/or prepared statements should be used." and it talks specifically about quotes.  I think this function is getting called somewhere on the server in a misguided attempt to prevent SQL injection.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php